# Listing the users who have actually submitted jobs in LSF

Tags: lsf

I am use the following command to list all users and there pending jobs in LSF:

```
busers -w all
```

Example output:

```
USER/GROUP   JL/P   MAX  NJOBS   PEND    RUN  SSUSP  USUSP    RSV  MPEND
aaaaa          -     -      0      0      0      0      0      0   200
bbbbb          -     -     100     50     50     0      0      0   200
ccccc          -     -      1      0      1      0      0      0   200
```

I'm looking for a command that will only display the users whose NJOBS value is greater than 0, i.e. those who have actually submitted at least one job.

In the example, that would mean that only the lines for users 'bbbbb' and 'ccccc' should appear.

Comment: `busers -w all | awk '$4>0'`

Answer (score 0):

To check all users jobs the simpler method would be:

```
bjobs -u all
```

To check suspended ones just use:

```
bjobs -u all | grep SUSP
```